# microsoft speech lib. Add custom language grammar,and train?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is it possible to add my own custom "words" as grammer, and can I train the engine to  recognise it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a dictation experience, or a command & control experience?  If it's dictation, you can add words using the [ISpLexicon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee450823%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface (or use the [Windows Speech Recognition Speech Dictionary](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Add-or-edit-words-in-the-Speech-Dictionary)).

For command & control, the words are implicit as part of the grammar.  If the word has an unusual pronunciation, you can explicitly declare the pronunciation as part of the token, using the [Display/Lexical/Pronunciation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) format or the PRON attribute.